# Help with if statement inside while loop

Tags: wp-query, metabox

I have the following snippet of code, basically I get the set value of id from the metabox, get the current id based on the loop, try and match, if htey match I want to pull the values from the matched id, currently i can only get the id, but i would like to get the associated custom field values of that post as well.

Also I don't know why, even if it matches the value, it will still echo out the else statement twice, i guess cause it's in the while loops, but how do i get ride of that?

```
<?php 
                  $list_agent = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'ec_agents',true );    
                  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'agent_type');  

                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    $id = $post->ID;
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                        if ($id == $list_agent) {
                            echo "success";
                            the_title();

                            //Both Meta values not showing
                            echo get_post_meta( $post->ID,'_agent_phone',true );
                            echo get_post_meta( $post->ID,'_agent_email',true );
                        } else {
                            echo "better luck next time";
                        }
                    endwhile;

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$id = $post->ID;` outside of the loop for `agent_type` posts, it'll never match.

Anyway, if you're not doing anything with the `agent_type` posts that don't match, just query for the one post you want by its ID:

```
$list_agent = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'ec_agents',true );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'agent_type',
    'p' => $list_agent
);
$agent_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $agent_query->have_posts() ) : $agent_query->the_post();
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'_agent_phone',true );
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'_agent_email',true );
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: see edited code above, maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do?

Comment: oh never mind, you figured it out!